# devise_invitable + omniauth-identity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, devise-invitable

I have been developing application that was implemented by omniauth-identity for users
authentication process but Now I need to implement invite users strategy where I would like to 
integrate devise_invitable.

I believing that devise_invitable only for apps implemented by devise for user authenitcation.

Can any one have idea about it? Please help me can I implement the devise_invitable for the
omniauth-identity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this? Can you gist your example code? I'd like to do something similar to this.